# Prediction biases in RandomForestRegressor when using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, random-forest, gridsearchcv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1trzf.png)

what parameter can be used for GridSearchCV and RandomForestRegressor to rotate the predictions, if removed so that the model shows the result much better?

```
start = time.time()

param_dists = {'max_features': ["sqrt", "log2", None], #по умолчанию None
               'max_depth': [None, range(1, 50)], #по умолчанию None
               'criterion': ['mae', 'squared_error'] #по умолчанию squared_error
              }



model_RandomForestRegressor_TuneSearchCV = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=270223)  

grid_RandomForestRegressor = GridSearchCV(model_RandomForestRegressor_TuneSearchCV,
                                          param_dists,
                                          cv=3,
                                          n_jobs=-1,
                                          scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')

grid_RandomForestRegressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_score = -1 * grid_RandomForestRegressor.best_score_
predict_dt = grid_RandomForestRegressor.predict(X_test)

time_hyperopt_RandomForestRegressor = round((time.time() - start), 2)

print("MAE модели случайного леса с гиперпараметрами:", best_score)
print('Лучшие параметры', grid_RandomForestRegressor.best_params_)


results_model = {'Модель': 'RandomForestRegressor с гиперпараметрами',
                 'MAE': best_score,
                 'Общее время':time_hyperopt_RandomForestRegressor
              }

results = results.append(results_model, ignore_index=True)
```

Metric - MAE

now MAE of random forest model with hyperparameters: 5.564043154396905
Best options {'criterion': 'mae', 'max_depth': None, 'max_features': None}

Comment: `what parameter can be used for GridSearchCV and RandomForestRegressor to rotate the predictions` Rotate predictions in what way?

Comment: https://ibb.co/3YN2fq8

It can be seen that RF predicts lines, and if you turn a few degrees of prediction, then there will be an almost ideal model.

Comment: The final goal is to improve MAE

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the implications of the results in your plot.

For the grouping in the middle, your model should output similar results, since they are all in a similar band of true values (y-axis), instead your model predicts a large variety of different values. This means that your model is NOT learning the underlying mapping.

You just need to train a better model.